# Checking three conditions (in every way) with if elif stataement

Tags: python

I am trying to check `three` statements if any of them or two of them is True or False.

But I don't know efficient way to check all three in `different ways` at same time.

There are `three Booleans` and I am trying to check like :-

1). If boolean_1 is `True` and boolean_2 and boolean_3 are False. *=>* `do something_1`

2). If boolean_2 is `True` and boolean_1 and boolean_3 are False. *=>* `do something_2`

3). If boolean_3 is `True` and boolean_1 and boolean_2 are False. *=>* `do something_3`

4). If boolean_1 and boolean_2 is `True` and boolean_3 is False. *=>* `do something_4`.

5). If boolean_1 and boolean_3 is `True` and boolean_2 is False. *=>* `do something_5`.

6). If boolean_2 and boolean_3 is `True` and boolean_1 is False. *=>* `do something_6`.

7). If boolean_1 is `True` and boolean_2 is `True` and boolean_3 is `True`. *=>* (and guess what) `do something_7`.

A way I can do is :-

file.py

```
if boo_1 == True and bool_2 == False and bool_3 == False:
    do_something_1

elif boo_2 == True and bool_1 == False and bool_3 == False:
    do_something_2

elif boo_3 == True and bool_2 == False and bool_1 == False:
    do_something_3

elif boo_1 == True and bool_2 == True and bool_3 == False:
    do_something_4

elif boo_1 == True and bool_3 == True and bool_2 == False:
    do_something_5

elif boo_2 == True and bool_3 == True and bool_1 == False:
    do_something_6

else:
    do_something_7
```

I can also use this lengthy `if elif` method But I don't know why I think that "This is not the efficient way". and I think this will slow. Will this slow ?

**Questions**

- Will this lengthy if elif method be slow ?
- Is there a more efficient way instead of this lengthy code ?

Any suggestions would much Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: The problem is that you have 7 cases to check, and you don't know which one to check first. Unless you have some way of ordering the checks from most to least likely, there's not much you can do.

Comment: First of all, you can replace `x == True` with `x` and `x == False` with `not x`.

Comment: Is the `do_something` the same for every case?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, No it's different Obviously

Comment: @chepner, It will be somewhat in a website, And How am i supposed to know which boolean will user turn to `True` and which to `False` ?

Comment: Do you really have only  *seven* cases (that is, do you do the same thing when all are true and when all are false)?

Comment: With something like this it might be interesting to experiment with the new Python 3.10 match cases construct (a sort of switch).

Comment: @Van No, it is not obvious that each `do_something` is different since you use the same name in each case. This is why I asked. If they are all the same, then you can reduce the if...elif chain to a single if...else.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Sorry, I am changing. Every statement to execute in if elif is different

Answer (score 6):

For cleaner code you don't need to check equality vs `True/False` as they already evaluate as that. Consider changing:

```
# from this
if boo_1 == True and bool_2 == False, bool_3 == True:
# to this
if boo_1 and not bool_2 and bool_3:
```

As for efficiency, consider arranging your `if`s so it needs to do the least amount of checks as possible to get it's result. Aside from that consider the below for other options.

Using a `dict` to determine what to do in each case:

```
switch = {
    (True, True, True): do_thing_1,
    (True, True, False): do_thing_2,
    (True, False, False): do_thing_3,
    (True, False, True): do_thing_4,
    ...
}
```

Then just access using your variables:

```
switch[(bool_1, bool_2, bool_3)](*args, **kwargs)
```

Or for an else clause use `dict.get`:

```
switch.get((bool_1, bool_2, bool_3), do_else)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using [Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) in python 3.10

```
match [bool_1, bool_2, bool_3]:
    case [True, False, False]:
        do_thing_1
    case [True, (True | False), False]: # to match a True or False
        do_thing_x
    case _:
        do_else
```

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy` and `dict` you can minimize rows

```
import numpy as np

bool_0 = False
bool_1 = True
bool_2 = True

t = [bool_0,bool_1,bool_2] # this is list of true/False index are [0,1,2]

switch = {0:"--0--",1:"--1--",2:"--2--",'01':"--01--",'12':'--12--','03':'--03--'} # these are conditions to follow

if bool_0+bool_1+bool_2 == 1:
    print(switch[np.where(t)[0][0]])
elif bool_0+bool_1+bool_2 == 2:
    print(switch[str(np.where(t)[0][0])+str(np.where(t)[0][1])])
else:
    print('Either all True or all False')
```

you need to change conditions inside `switch dict` keeping `keys` as it is

Answer (score 1):

Well, on such a small scale I doubt this will make any difference, but you could cut it down by if/else in a branched way:

```
if boo_1:
    if boo_2:
        if boo_3:
            do_something
        else:
            do_something
    else:
        if boo_3:
            do_something
        else:
            do_something
else:
    if boo_2:
        if boo_3:
            do_something
        else:
            do_something
    else:
        if boo_3:
            do_something
        else:
            do_something
```

This way you can in best case cut down the number checks down.
In your best case, it checks already 3 times, in worst case 18 times. Just to get the conclusion that all have been False. With each if/elif statement it must check for 3 conditions.
If you do it in a branched way, it must check in best case 3 conditions, as well as in worst case.
The difference is not big, but there is a difference.
I quick wrote a program which got to assign to boo_1 to boo_3 a random 0 or 1 and check it through the branched if/else statements and your if/elif/else statement.

After 1mio runs, the branched function had an average duration of 2.8696 sec while your construct had 3.0864 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

```
trues = boo_1 + boo_2 + boo_3

if trues == 3:
    # all three are true
    # stuff
elif trues == 2:
    # two are true, one is false
    if not boo_1:
        # stuff
    elif not boo_2:
        # stuff
    else: # not boo_3
        # stuff
elif trues == 1:
    # one is true, two are false
    if boo_1:
        # stuff
    elif boo_2:
        # stuff
    else: # boo_3
        # stuff
else: # trues == 0
    # all three are false
    # stuff
```

---

Going along the theme of encoding the True/False values, you can encode them as a three-bit number `enc = boo_3 * 4 + boo_2 * 2 + boo_1` (i.e. `boo_3` in the *four*'s place, `boo_2` in the *two*'s place, and `boo_1` in the *one*'s place. Then you can do:

Using `enc` you do:

```
if enc == 0b00: # 0 meaning all three are false
    ...
elif enc == 0b001: # 1 meaning boo_1 is true
    ...
elif enc == 0b010: # 2 meaning boo_2 is true
    ...
elif enc == 0b011: # 3 meaning boo_2 and boo_1 are true
...
elif enc == 0b110: # 6 meaning boo_3 and boo_2 are true
    ...
else: # enc == 0b111, i.e. 7 meaning all three are true
    ...
```

Or you can do:

```
actions = [action0, action1, ..., action7]
action = actions[enc]
action(...)
```

where `action<n>` is a function corresponding to what should happen when `enc == n`.